# How to bring down/reduce the SharePoint DB Server memory usage?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, database, database-server

For our SharePoint 2013 application, we are using

- 2 Web Servers
- 2 APP
- 2 DB

One of the DB server memory usage is about 78%. 
(Windows Server 2012 with 16 GB RAM, where sqlserver.exe takes upto 9 GB)

I want to ***bring down the memory usage*** to around 50 - 60%, without restarting the SQLService (i.e. No down time for users).

Is there any option ?

Comment: I tried recycling all the application pools in the Web & App Servers. But no change in memory usage of this DB server. Still 78%

Comment: try restarting SQL Server (SharePoint) service. it would release some unneeded resources.

Answer (score 3):

SQL server by DESIGN will always eat up as much ram as you throw at it if you have databases of sufficient size. Have a 32GB database and 32GB of memory ... SQL by default will eat all of it.

You can configure SQL to limit the amount of memory it will consume however. Lets say you have 16GB of memory in your system try limiting the SQL buffer to 10GB, that will leave 6GB or so for the host OS, other SQL processes, and any other programs to use ( ex: your other SQL express instance). Then monitor the memory consumption on the system and then tweak your buffer up or down depending on how much memory you still have available.

So you dont need to worry about it.SQL Server is usually pretty good at sharing RAM and managing memory in general.SQL Server is a good neighbor, though, and if other programs want some memory, SQL Server will free up some memory for them—most of the time.

http://sharepointpromag.com/sql-server-2012/fine-tune-your-sql-server-2012-configuration-sharepoint-2013

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

**Real issue with SQL server arise when CPU usage goes up**